# Question locking prevented answering

Tags: discussion

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267749/calculating-if-date-falls-within-a-given-range) about 10 minutes after it was posted (I remember seeing that it had been posted 8 minutes ago when I loaded it the first time).

But my post was rejected because it had been locked by "Community ♦" (with the diamond of a moderator).

Now I reloaded the question and see an answer very similar to the one I would have posted and so I'm discouraged from posting my own answer. That is frustrating!

Could you explain what was going on? Is this kind of thing going to be a frequent occurrence here?

Comment: I honestly don't know.

Comment: @jcolebrand Could it be that my post came from the dba side after it had been migrated to SO?

Comment: oooh, yeah, I missed that the first time I read this ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You filled in the missing blanks for me.

The question was migrated while you were answering, so that's what happened. This is an "engine" problem that can't easily be fixed.

Sorry to hear that happened to you.